# Trouble displaying fonts size properly in IE 9

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9

On the site http://hanling.focusww.com

The header text in the h2 tags is huge in IE 9 compared to Firefox, Chrome, or Safari.

I'm looking for suggestions to fix this.

This is a wordpress site.

(this post was migrated from the Wordpress Stack exchange)

Suggested answer:
if you do migrate check this out for a possible answer.

Seems IE9 doesn't play nice with all fonts so you might want to supply your own for IE9 to read see here https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/3116 and here [@font-face works in IE8 but not IE9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4607560/font-face-works-in-ie8-but-not-ie9)

Seems like a font-weight issue

response: 
We are not embedding any fonts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer lies within your `font-family` declaration:

```
font-family: Bookman, serif;
```

If *Bookman* is not found, the browser falls back to the next available font in the chain. In this case you only have one fall back and that is set to *serif*.

The issue is that Firefox is falling back to its default serif font: *Times New Roman*, and IE9 is falling back its default serif font (which is different): *Batang*. You can sort this issue out by changing the declaration to something like:

```
font-family: Bookman, "Times New Roman", serif;
```

So now it would fall back to Times New Roman first, and if that font is not available then it will fall back to *serif* which will be the browsers default serif font.

Comment: @MrLister: I am pretty sure you cannot set what the default **serif** font is in IE9. You can set the default font, which is to say, if no font-family is set or the font(s) cannot be found then it will use the font chosen in the Options, but not if **serif** has been declared as a font choice.

Comment: I'm sorry, I was so sure I remembered that you could change that in the registry. But you're right, I must have misremembered. My apologies.

Comment: @MrLister: No problem. The other point of course is that even if you could do it, it wouldn't really be a viable solution. Because given it is a website, you can't really get every visitor to change their default settings.