# IE font size different to Chrome

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've created a message board (Within an iframe) which uses Bootstrap's CSS.

Both font size's are at 14px, and everything else is the same, yet IE's font size is way smaller than Chromes.

To get IE the same, I have to bump it up to 24px. Is there any way to forcefully standardize this?

[image]

**Update**
*Both* their fonts are `font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;`
*Uploaded the correct pic (Without me changing things UI side).*

Comment: `font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;` try this?

Comment: This might give you some direction, although i am no font expert http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13561111/font-face-not-working-in-ie-10

Comment: @l2aelba Tried it... Same result sadly

Answer (score 1):

Notice how IE is using a serif font whereas Chrome is using a sans-serif one?

This means IE didn't recognise your `font-family` CSS, or you're using a custom font file that IE can't read.

Either way, try looking at the Developer Tools to inspect your element, and look in the CSS rules - if your font is crossed out, that means it doesn't like your `font-family` rule. Otherwise, it doesn't like the font itself.

Comment: They both have `font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;`, and IE hasn't striked it out. **EDIT**: Even when I change the font to `Arial` on both, the size stay the same.