# Text rendering is absolutely awful in IE9

Tags: html, internet-explorer, text, internet-explorer-9, typekit

See attached screenshot... This text rendering is coming out very unclearly on IE9. You may wish to zoom in to full size.

[image: IE9 text rendering]

The font is from Typekit and, as per the client's request (and visual necessity), needs the drop shadow underneath it. This is done with CSS3. Is this a known issue, or are there any workarounds to it?

Is this to do with ClearType etc? If so, which settings need to be changed to fix this?

Thanks for your advice! Here's what the CSS on the text looks like:

```
font-family: "proxima-nova", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
font-weight: 700;
color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
text-shadow: 0px 5px 10px #000;
display: inline;
margin-right: 30px;
font-size: 30px;
cursor: pointer;
```

Comment: I have a similar issue with silverlight text rendering. The text looks great in Chrome, but in ie9 its horrible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what your issue here is, but I do know that `text-shadow` isn't supported by default IE9. The text will appear perfectly white in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YpEvP/) using your example code in IE9. Unless you're using some shiv to get `text-shadow` to work, you can use a DirectX filter - `DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow` - to apply the shadow in IE9:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#000000,direction=45);
```

Do note, however, that this will not be as dark as the `text-shadow` you have currently applied.

If this issue is to do with the font not displaying in IE9 (it looks like Arial to me), then please see [@font-face works in IE8 but not IE9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4607560/font-face-works-in-ie8-but-not-ie9)

Comment: Got it. I actually saw I was using `filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.DropShadow` (rather than just `Shadow`). I tried with both but the antialiasing still looks terrible either way, which is a shame. For now, I've had to turn it off. This might just be one of those things you can't work around :(