# Font for all ie browser version (6 to 10)

Tags: css, internet-explorer, fonts

I am trying to find the code that can render font for IE versions 6 to 10. I tested the code from [font squirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/), [adobe webfonts](http://html.adobe.com/edge/webfonts/) and Google's font css but there is no code that works for all IE browsers.

Does anyone have the code for that?

Comment: What are "all IE versions"? Font-Face is available since Version 6 and examples of how to use them are in the fontsquirrel-css files.

Comment: All IE versions, really? From version 1 on? What is the actual problem and with which IE version?

Comment: What's wrong with Google web fonts? It supports IE 6+ https://developers.google.com/webfonts/faq#Browsers_Supported

Comment: This question has an answer for a IE font-fix, but also contains the syntax you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4607560/font-face-works-in-ie8-but-not-ie9

Comment: Sorry, I mean 6 to 10. I test the fontsquirrel-css file in ie10. It does not work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I believe both of those services provide the code for all browsers that are supported, including IE, automatically.

For example, calling a font from Google font API with the style tag, will actually pull in a CSS file from Google with different font declarations.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Karla:400,400italic,700,700italic" />
```

**Generates the following CSS:**

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Karla';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Karla'), local('Karla-Regular'), url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/karla/v2/QT0qO2FiFD03cwUe_t62t6CWcynf_cDxXwCLxiixG1c.woff) format('woff');
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Karla';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  src: local('Karla Bold'), local('Karla-Bold'), url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/karla/v2/3nZS3BKzlvhkwl4yjCQcjHYhjbSpvc47ee6xR_80Hnw.woff) format('woff');
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Karla';
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Karla Italic'), local('Karla-Italic'), url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/karla/v2/ietJ6bjhwzrJL8NSJOc2mgLUuEpTyoUstqEm5AMlJo4.woff) format('woff');
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Karla';
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 700;
  src: local('Karla Bold Italic'), local('Karla-BoldItalic'), url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/karla/v2/VZ08RdiotRdV1D0ewK-mxL3hpw3pgy2gAi-Ip7WPMi0.woff) format('woff');
}
```

As you can see, there are different formats for different browsers. WOFF is for IE.

Mikey.

**PS - Something I mentioned in the comments below:**

Are you working and viewing this in IE locally? If so, it may not work. For it to work in IE, I think you have to be viewing the website on an actual server. Something to do with the 'headers' and origin policy in IE - it's a security thing. Could that be it?

Comment: I does not check with other version now. But it does not work in ie10.

Comment: Are you working and viewing this in IE locally? If so, it may not work. For it to work in IE, I think you have to be viewing the website on an actual server. Something to do with the 'headers' and origin policy in IE - it's a security thing. Could that be it?

Comment: Thanks! I will check it with actual server.