# font-face & IE8?

Tags: internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, font-face

I'm loading two fonts with font-face on my css.
The first font works on IE7/8, the second one doesn't. The css code is identical for both fonts.
Any idea how to fix that? :(

Here is the html page : http://canapin.com/web/fonts.html

And the css : http://canapin.com/web/fonts.html

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'nexa_bold';
    src: url('./fonts/Nexa Bold.eot?');
    src: url('./fonts/Nexa Bold.woff') format('woff'),
         url('./fonts/Nexa Bold.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('./fonts/Nexa Bold.svg') format('svg');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'signika';
    src: url('./fonts/Signika-Regular.eot?');
    src: url('./fonts/Signika-Regular.woff') format('woff'),
         url('./fonts/Signika-Regular.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('./fonts/Signika-Regular.svg') format('svg');
}

h1 {
    font-family: 'nexa_bold';
}

h1.alt {
    font-family: 'signika';
}
```

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4607560/font-face-works-in-ie8-but-not-ie9

Comment: Thank you! I used the font generated by font2web and it didn't work.
I guess I'll use fontsquirrel now.