# How to bind a new web font to an open html page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i'm not sure if it's the right place to post this question ?

I've read this morning that the new version of Chrome support live binding web font.

Is there a trick javascript, dom manipulation, Amberjs or Jquery plug-in to do the same to the browser that doesn't support that feature yet (to add a new web font in a open page in the browser and have access to it, i mean without to have to change the css and reload the page ?)

thanks :)

Comment: I suspect you've misunderstood what "live binding" is, but I can't find any documentation about it. Where did you read this?

Comment: @Quentin i have read this here [link](http://www.macg.co/logiciels/2014/05/chrome-35-la-version-stable-disponible-pour-os-x-82082) but it is in french sorry

Comment: It looks like [this is the relevant specification](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-font-loading/). It does a number of different things, but "dynamically altering the CSS to include a new @font-face rule" isn't something you couldn't do already AFAIK.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var newStyleText = "@font-face {" +
"font-family: myFirstFont;" +
"src: url(your-font.css);" +
"}"

var newStyle = $(document.createElement("style");
newStyle.html(newStyleText);
$(document.head).append(newStyle)
```

every element with `font-family: myFirstFont;` while use your font!

Comment: The question is asking about using JS to add a web font to an already loaded page.

Comment: and you can create an stylesheet with js! use docuement.createStylesheet! or $(document.createElement('link'))

Comment: Try forming that into a proper answer instead of a comment.

Comment: @Mohsen89z i prefer the way you describe it, with just javascript but could you make an answer with example, instead of a comment. thanks anyway

Comment: Just a stupid (or not) question i should have ask from the start, does it work the same for AngularJS

Answer (score 0):

As @Mohsen89z said, you can use @font-face.

Cite from w3schools:

> The @font-face rule is supported in Internet Explorer 9, Firefox,
>   Opera, Chrome, and Safari.
>
> Internet Explorer 9+, Firefox, Chrome, Safari, and Opera support the
>   WOFF (Web Open Font Format) font.
>
> Firefox, Chrome, Safari, and Opera also support fonts of type TTF
>   (True Type Fonts) and OTF (OpenType Fonts).
>
> Chrome, Safari and Opera also support SVG fonts/shapes.
>
> Internet Explorer also supports EOT (Embedded OpenType) fonts.
>
> Note: Internet Explorer 8 and earlier versions, do not support the
>   @font-face rule.

Anyway, there is a trick to use on IE previous versions. Check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6062692/3648578).

Then, if you want to change the font, use JS for that.
Example with jQuery:

```
$('.myparagraph').css('font', 'normal "Your fav font", sans-serif');
```

To extend my asnwer, I recommend you to use Google Fonts to embed all fonts that you need into a single  tag line, like:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Finger+Paint|Gloria+Hallelujah|Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Then, you can use it directly from your css `.mydiv { font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif; }` or js (example above)

Comment: As note, I have to say: this is NOT new. You can vote negative to a valid answer anyway. There is no need to create `<link>` tags if you use js directly