# font-face not working in IE9 only

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9, font-face, webfonts, eot

I've seen several questions asked here and on other blogs but it didn't solve my case. This is my syntax:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "texgyreheroscn";
    src: url("texgyreheroscn-italic-webfont.eot");
    src: url("texgyreheroscn-italic-webfont.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
         url("texgyreheroscn-italic-webfont.woff") format("woff"),
         url("texgyreheroscn-italic-webfont.ttf") format("truetype"),
         url("texgyreheroscn-italic-webfont.svg#texgyreheroscnitalic") format("svg");
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

this works everywhere **except** in IE9 (IE8 works too). The syntax looks fine to me, the .eot file is on the server and has permissions to be accessed.

i've tried

- adding `src: local('☺︎'),` - this breaks the font for every browser (as seen on [@font-face works in IE8 but not IE9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4607560/font-face-works-in-ie8-but-not-ie9))
- asked the backend guys if the .eot font was there and was accessible and the answer is YES
- substituted the `"` with `'`
- added `format("embedded-opentype")` on the first `src:` line

nothing seems to work for me. any heads up on this? thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [@font-face works in IE8 but not IE9](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4607560/font-face-works-in-ie8-but-not-ie9)

Comment: @Aziz as i wrote in my question, I have already tried that solution which didn't work for me